# Is it possible to set a default value for checkboxes in Powermail?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, powermail

I would like to transmit yes or no as value for checkboxes in Powermail (marketing.sendpost.values). If the checkbox is not selected, nothing is transmitted by default. Is it possible to set a default value per checkbox?
I have created the checkbox with `Text|yes` in TYPO3.

My TypoScript

```
300 = TEXT
300 {
   data = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|testcheckbox|0
   stdWrap {
       required = 1
       wrap = &testcheckbox=|
    }
    ifEmpty.wrap = &testcheckbox=no
}
```

but this does not work yet. The default value is used, but the empty field is also transmitted.
e.g.
Checkbox checked:

```
&testcheckbox=yes
```

Checkbox not checked

```
&testcheckbox=&testcheckbox=no
```

Why does it take the `&testcheckbox=` in the empty checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works. Maybe it helps someone else.

```
300 = TEXT
300 {
    value = &testcheckbox=no
    override {
        cObject = TEXT
        cObject {
            required = 1
            data = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|testcheckbox|0
            wrap = &testcheckbox=|
        }
    }
}
```